# TSC error message upon installation. Do not know how to solve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I have been trying to install typescript globally so I can add it to my websites. Once I install it, I try to use tsc but I always get this error message

```
C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
+ typescript@4.1.3
updated 1 package in 6.831s
PS C:\Users\raahi\OneDrive\Desktop\Typescript Tutorial> tsc --version
tsc : File C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

what do I do to solve this?

Comment: Did you read the Microsoft page it links to, or about execution policies generally?

Comment: @joesharpe, yes I did and I still don't understand

Comment: "because running scripts is disabled on this system"

Comment: @hoangdv, how do I enable running scripts then?